# Data for UiTableView with sections + UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a tableview and a segmented control in a view controller such that tableview reloads the data based on the segment index when user switches to another segment.
And data for this is stored in a two dimensional array like this

```
var data = [
        ["Soccer",       "Golf",      "Basketball",    "AmericanFootball",
         "Baseball",     "Tennis",    "Valleyball",    "Badminton"],
        ["Apple",        "Pear",      "Strawberry",    "Avocado",
         "Banana",       "Grape",     "Melon",         "Orange",
         "Peach",        "Kiwi"]
    ]
```

I want to introduce sections in the tableview now. What is the best way to organize the above data so that it can have section information too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create

```
struct Item {
   let title:String
   let arr:[String]
}
```

Then

```
let data  = [ Item(title:"First",arr: ["Soccer","Golf","Basketball", "AmericanFootball","Baseball","Tennis","Valleyball","Badminton"]) , 
             Item(title:"Second",arr: ["Apple","Pear" ,"Strawberry","Avocado","Banana", "Grape","Melon","Orange","Peach", "Kiwi"])
]
```

---

To make the content for every segment

```
let data : [[Item]] = [ [ Item(title:"Section 1 seg 1",arr: ["Soccer","Golf","Basketball", "AmericanFootball","Baseball","Tennis","Valleyball","Badminton"]) , 
             Item(title:"Section 2 seg 1",arr: ["Apple","Pear" ,"Strawberry","Avocado","Banana", "Grape","Melon","Orange","Peach", "Kiwi"])
   ] ,

 [ Item(title:"Section 1 seg 2",arr: ["Soccer","Golf","Basketball", "AmericanFootball","Baseball","Tennis","Valleyball","Badminton"]) , 
             Item(title:"Section 2 seg 2",arr: ["Apple","Pear" ,"Strawberry","Avocado","Banana", "Grape","Melon","Orange","Peach", "Kiwi"])
  ]
]
```

Comment: Hey! This probably works for just one section in the tableview for the selected segment. How do I scale this to have multiple sections in the tableview for a segment

Comment: The first Item in this array is going to be the data for the table view in my first segment. Similarly the second item is the data for the table view in my second segment

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is this going to be better than having dictionary?

Comment: a model is always better than raw dictionary